# Is it possible to find all the config file replacements done during apt-get?

Tags: apt, upgrade, dpkg, log

When you perform a `do-release-upgrade`, or just a `dist-upgrade`, if a package contains a new config file for a program, you get prompted what to do. Now, you can pick whether you want to accept maintainer's version, keep your own, and so on.

It happens that I just press `Y` at a config file after while I did wanted to keep my changes. I do have a backup, I do know what changes I made, but I cannot find which file got replaced.

**Is there a way to find these packages where the user got prompted?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For any configuration file for which `apt` has posed a question, `apt` will keep a backup based on the action you took.

- If you chose to replace the current file with the package file, the original will be saved with the extension `dpkg-old`.
- If you chose to keep the current file, the new one from the package will be kept with the extension `dpkg-dist`.

Therefore, you can look for files with such extensions:

```
find /etc -type f -name '*.dpkg-*'
```